life insurance found after years
My husband retired from the U.S. Air Force in 1976 and died in 2005.  My son just found a paper saying he had a life insurance policy paid for through his pension with the U.S. government.  How do I apply for this It was through Life insurance of New York?

What documentation do you have ? Is there a policy number?

This site may be able to help you:   https://eapps.naic.org/life-policy-locator/#/decedent

Call New York Life. Given your husbands SSN they should be able to indicate if there is a policy on him. Having the policy number will certainly help. However, I'm surprised that it did not come to light when his pension plan was notified of his death.

And call them now, just in case there is a clause that after 20 years they don't need to pay anymore. There may not be any such clause, or it may be 10 years (you lost) or 30 years (you have plenty of time) but you don't want to take that risk.
